# unable to find record in recodset

Tags: ms-access, vba

I just starting with access and cant make things work...
trying to make simple sub that opens excell sheet and compares some values with table in access.
I am using this link as a reference:
http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Recordsets_for_Beginners

```
  Private Sub Command2_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = openXLS

If Not wb Is Nothing Then

    Dim rcs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim db As Database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rcs = db.OpenRecordset(TABLE_PRODUCTS)
    Dim itemNo As String


    For i = 1 To tools.LRow(wb.Sheets("Sheet1"), "A")
        itemNo = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Value

        rcs.FindFirst "ItemNo = " & itemNo 'error here, runtime error 3251
                                           'operation is not supported for this type of object

        If rcs.NoMatch = True Then
            MsgBox "nomatch"
        Else
            MsgBox "OK"
        End If

    Next i

    wb.Close
    rcs.Close

    Set wb = Nothing
    Set rcs = Nothing

End If
```

End Sub

`openXLS` is  a function that opens and returns `workbook`.
`LRow` returns last row in the column

i get runtime error 3251 operation is not supported for this type of object (marked in the coments)

Comment: You mentioned what you have used and what is your intention, so what is your question?

Comment: the question is how to get rid of the error marked in the comments :)

Comment: You should use Option Explicit and compile. Does `TABLE_PRODUCTS` have a value ? It is not declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use FindFirst with table type recordsets. You will need to explicitly specify a dynaset recordset:-

```
Set rcs = db.OpenRecordset(TABLE_PRODUCTS, dbOpenDynaset)
```

Comment: thanks for your coment. I tried that, it did not worked. I also tried to use `rs.RecordCount` to get number of record. before using you suggestion it was 47, after i used `dbOpenDynaset` it was 1

Comment: The recordCount is not accurate until you have moved to the end of the recordset! i.e you need to use .MoveLast before checking .RecordCount

Comment: oh, OK, thanks for pointing that out! it returned 47 with `dbOpenDynaset` property and after i called `.MoveLast`.
but still geting the same error. Maybe the syntax is wrong?

Comment: Yes, the syntax was also wrong. it worked when I changed to `rs.FindFirst "[ItemNo] = '" & itemNo & "'"`
so `dbOpenDynaset` do the trick. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this because i think you are not getting any records in recordset

```
if not rcs.EOF then
   rcs.FindFirst "ItemNo = " & itemNo 'error here, runtime error 3251
                                       'operation is not supported for this type of object

    If rcs.NoMatch = True Then
        MsgBox "nomatch"
    Else
        MsgBox "OK"
    End If
end if
```

**Update**

Can you try using seek method instead of findfirst

```
rcs.Seek "=", itemNo
```

**Update 2**

First set index of your primary id like

```
rcs.index= "Id" -- do this after you create DAO recordset
```

Then try this

```
rcs.Seek Comparison:="=", itemNo:=itemNo
```

Comment: i tried your sugestion and that did not solved the problem. function `MsgBox rs.RecordCount` returned 47 so I gues recordset is not empty...

Comment: I alredy make it work with `dbOpenDynaset` property, but I am intrested in you sugestion. it did not worked, but `ItemNo`is actually a string, so maybe syntax has to be different for a string?